# get values from keys with foreach (multidimensional array)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, key

I have a multidimensional array

```
(Array ( [filenames] => Array ( [0] => 2.jpeg [1] => 3.jpeg ) [sizes] => Array ( [0] => 0.00 MB [1] => 0.00 MB ) [temp_names] => Array ( [0] => /private/var/folders/np/sln14hvn3tsbzc4kpjjtp17c0000gn/T/phpLVhmBY [1] => /private/var/folders/np/sln14hvn3tsbzc4kpjjtp17c0000gn/T/phpoifsg0 ) [uploads] => Array ( [0] => /Users/sandro/Documents/bildgalerie/uploads/2.jpeg [1] => /Users/sandro/Documents/bildgalerie/uploads/3.jpeg ) ))
```

and I want to get all values from specific keys (like "filenames") with foreach.

Here is the part of the array:

```
$uploadData = array(
    'filenames' => array(),
    'sizes' => array(),
    'temp_names' => array(),
    'uploads' => array()
);
```

This code doesn't work yet, but I have no idea why :(

```
foreach ($uploadData as $row) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($row['temp_names'], $location . '/' . basename($row['filenames']))) {
        echo 'File uploaded.';
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Error: `Notice: Undefined index: filenames in X on line X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're failing to understand what `foreach` is doing and how arrays are structured. It iterates over each element of the given array. You've said your data looks like this:

```
$uploadData = [
    'filenames' => ["2.jpeg", "3.jpeg"],
    'sizes' => ["0.00 MB", "0.00 MB"],
    'temp_names' => ["/private/var/folders/np/sln14hvn3tsbzc4kpjjtp17c0000gn/T/phpLVhmBY", "/private/var/folders/np/sln14hvn3tsbzc4kpjjtp17c0000gn/T/phpoifsg0"],
    'uploads' => ["/Users/sandro/Documents/bildgalerie/uploads/2.jpeg", "/Users/sandro/Documents/bildgalerie/uploads/3.jpeg"],
];
```

So, this is an array with 4 elements. Each iteration of the loop will give you a new element. First iteration you get an array `["2.jpeg", "3.jpeg"]` and you're trying to access the `filenames` element of that array. Obviously there isn't one.

Instead you can just loop over one of the sub-arrays:

```
foreach ($uploadData["filenames"] as $key => $value) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($uploadData["temp_names"][$key], $location . '/' . basename($value))) {
        echo 'File uploaded.';
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

On the first iteration, `$key` will be `0` and `$value` will be `2.jpeg`. You can use that key to get the matching values in the other sub-arrays.

Comment: That will do it :)